# Does GitHub Swift Actions supports automatic provisioning updates?

Tags: swift, provisioning-profile, xcodebuild, github-actions

I'm fairly new to the topic, so over 3 days scrolling the internet did not make some good clarification. I'll be happy for any help.

I have a project, which I want to equip with build-passing/failing badge: https://github.com/Wtclrsnd/PhotoEditPod

I use workflow by [Swift Actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/swift-action) for now.

The thing I get all the time is:

```
error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode (in target 'PhotoEditPod' from project 'PhotoEditPod')
error: No profiles for 'com.daksyonov.PhotoEditPod' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.daksyonov.PhotoEditPod'. (in target 'PhotoEditPod' from project 'PhotoEditPod')
```

[Workflow log](https://github.com/Wtclrsnd/PhotoEditPod/runs/816073245?check_suite_focus=true#step:3:10)

As I read from the documentation - Actions handle build by themselves by GitHub hosted runners, but what I get confused with - why `no accounts` and `no profiles` if I enabled automatic signing?

Maybe I am missing something? I have other Ideas:

- I need to create manual profile, thus need a paid developer account @ Apple
- I have overlooked some xcodebuild guidance
- Xcode on GitHub side needs some set-up before good to go (though I didnt' find any note on this)
- Maybe I need to log in to my appleID on GH Runner? (which seems not so feasible)

**So far my code for this is:**

```
 name: Swift

 on:
   push:
     branches: [ master ]
   pull_request:
     branches: [ master ]

 jobs:
   build:

     runs-on: macos-latest
     strategy:
       matrix:
         destination: ['platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13.5,name=iPhone 11 Pro Max']

     steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@master
     - name: Build
       run: xcodebuild clean && xcodebuild -allowProvisioningUpdates
```

Thank you in advance! Appreciate your help!
Regards